# How to track m2m field changes in django?

Tags: python, django, m2m

I need something like **m2m_changed** signal:

```
def event_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   pass
m2m_changed.connect(event_handler, sender=MyModel.tags.through)
```

but i want to know previous state of **instance.tags** in **event_handler**

Comment: I need to do some action if tags were changed.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you have found the solution by now. However for others reference, you can do that by checking the `kwargs['action'] == "pre_add"` or `kwargs['action'] == "pre_remove"` to check the value before any update happens. You can find more details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#m2m-changed).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed

You should be able to use the `action` and `pk_set`   parameters of the signal handler to figure out what happened.

Comment: This is not working for me. I am working with django-admin. When i change my model i have always 2 queries: delete all m2m fields from Model and then add m2m fields from POST query to my Model. For instance, I have a Model with m2m fields [3,6,7,8]. I want to delete a field "8". When i do it i have 2 signals (4 technically, but it does not matter): the first is **pre/post_clear** with **pk_set** is **None** and the second is **pre/post_add** with **pk_set** is **[3,6,7]**. So I dont know what happened in signal handler.

Comment: In `pre_remove`, `pre_clear` and `pre_add` you should be able to access `instance.tags` to get the tags *before* the change.